# Amazon hosting - CPU stuck at 100% since friday

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm not too experienced with server hosting at this level, but I was instructed to create a site on amazon hosting. it has worked well until friday, when it suddenly started to lag massively, and occasionally just not open at all. Looking at the EC2 instance on the backend revealed that the CPU has been stuck at 100% for days.On friday, I used filezilla to download the entire site to my computer, as we've been thinking of migrating to a simpler host. all in all I downloaded 14 gigabytes of files, and no doubt that has a hand in this. however, I'm not copying anymore, so I'm not sure what could still be causing it.  I'm not sure what is causing this, can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Redis?

Comment: What are you running on that instance?

Comment: @RaraituL I'm sorry, I'm not too sure what Redis is, this is quite new to me

Comment: Have you tried Rebooting the instance (from the Actions menu)? Have you tried connecting and using `top` to view the processes?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did reboot the instance through the actions menu, to no avail. I will try to connect through putty to try the top command

Comment: Reddis is a Cache - under ElasticCache, or you could have installed it yourself. I think this is unlikely to be the explanation though.
It's going to be hard to diagnose remotely... What do you mean exactly by 'to no avail'?

Comment: What I mean is the problem was still there after the reboot. I'm going to try stopping it and starting it again after 5 minutes

Comment: Interesting. I'd definitely be looking at `top` on the instance itself to see what is eating CPU.

Comment: @RaraituL curious why you ask this question about redis? I have an ec2 instance that occasionally spikes to 100% and stays there, and it is running redis - is that a known issue?

Comment: @E.J.Brennan we used to have the same issues with Redis, more especially with `StackExchange.Redis` library. In some scenarios, if you create many instances of `IConnectionMultiplexer`, the CPU goes to 100%. Also, same behavior if you use SignalR Redis backplane

Comment: Yea, that is what I am seeing - and I am using the StackExchange redis. For lack  of a better solution, a daily scheduled reboot 'solves' the issue for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If reboot is not working try to stop and start the instance after 5 or 10 minutes . Stop and start will change the underlying host of EC2 Instance .

Stop and start instance will have the following effect make sure it will be okay for you .

1. Ip address will be changed of ec2 instance .
2. Instance store (Not EBS) volume data will be erased .

if it still continue try to take AMI and launch the instance with more cpu .

Comment: Hi, I've tried this, but now I can't reach the server at all anymore

Comment: I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: check apache or whatever web server you are using  is running or not . please restart  . also check the security group inbound rules